# proper way to install skype x86-64 in ubuntu 12.04 after recent skype upgrade

Tags: skype

i'm having problens installing or upgrading skype in ubuntu 12.04 x86-64 after recent skype upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

it says skype depends on skype-bin and I'm having held packages. I purged skype abd skype-bin and all it's dependancies but still no go. Why does it happen on LTS which I use in my office??

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: of no use. It runs ok.

Comment: after recent apt-get update everything goes fine. skype is installed. The question why does it happen with LTS distro recommended by Canonical to run at critical machines still persists.

Comment: damn, now the microphone is not workingALSA lib conf.c:3314:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library ALSA lib dlmisc.c:254:(snd1_dlobj_cache_get) Cannot open shared library /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so

Comment: @netcat, I think you should add an `Update` section in your question body, explaining your current state and actual question.

Answer (score 3):

Errors like absence of `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so` means that Skype needs `libasound2-plugins:i386`.

So my recipe that helps me is to run the following command:

```
apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with 12.10. It seems a dependency problem.

I simply installed skype-bin first and then skype and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me. (the skype downloaded from the website it self directly gave me errors.
http://xchamitha.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/install-skype-in-ubuntu-1304.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. So, you should [edit] your answer and include those commands mentioned in that blog.