# Skype Ubuntu 13.04 64bit

Tags: 13.04, skype

When I try to install Skype on Ubuntu 13.04 I get the following error:

```
error cannot install 'libasound2:i386' from ubuntu software center
```

If I try through terminal I get:

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies
libasound2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386(>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed.
```

I've tried in terminal

sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugings:i386

it too has unmet dependencies

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/220636/proper-way-to-install-skype-x86-64-in-ubuntu-12-04-after-recent-skype-upgrade

Comment: I am facing the same issue. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

i know a simpler solution. go to software and updates and tick the repository canonical patners software. then update the package list. you can now install skype from software center.